# ¿Como copiar el contenido de una lista enlaza a una lista enlazada auxiliar?

Tags: c, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo una lista enlazada en `C` para guardar datos de una compañía telefónica
lo que quiero lograr es copiar todos los datos de la lista enlazada a otra lista auxiliar para eliminar los duplicados

Aquí esta mi código,soy novato en `C` y en esta pagina.Espero me puedan ayudar
Es un pequeño proyecto que estoy llevando acabo para final de semestre.
También tengo una idea de eliminar un duplicado y solo dejar uno pero me funciona de la forma que borra los 2 duplicados

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Node{
    int codigo;
    char nombre[20];
    char tipo[20];
    struct Node *next;
};

void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_codigo, char new_nombre[20], char new_tipo[20]){
    struct Node *new_node=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->codigo = new_codigo;
    strcpy(new_node->nombre,new_nombre);
    strcpy(new_node->tipo,new_tipo);
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

void deleteNode(struct Node **head_ref, int key){
    struct Node* temp = *head_ref, *prev;

    if(temp != NULL && temp->codigo == key){
        *head_ref = temp->next;

        free(temp);

        return;
    }

    while(temp != NULL && temp->codigo != key){
        prev = temp;
        temp= temp->next;
    }

    if(temp==NULL)return;

    prev->next = temp->next;
    free(temp);
}

void printList(struct Node *node){
    while(node != NULL){
        printf("%d\t",node->codigo);
        printf("%s\t",node->nombre);
        printf("%s\n",node->tipo);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void menu(){
    printf("               Menu              \n");
    printf("___________________________________ \n");
    printf("Seleccione lo que desea realizar:\n");
    printf("         1. Insertar\n");
    printf("         2. Eliminar\n");
    printf("         3. Mostrar\n");
    printf("         4. Salir\n");
    printf("__________________________________ \n");
    printf("?:");
}
```

Comment: De todo el código que has compartido ¿qué es lo que falla?

Comment: Hasta ahora nada,solo quiero saber la forma para copiar los datos de la lista enlazada para otra auxiliar (manipulare la auxiliar)

Comment: Para copiar los datos, recorre tu lista actual y copialos en una nueva.